# How to replace "0:00" with "Collect" in timer button

Tags: javascript, html, button, replace, timer

In the last days I had asked a question how to make a button that is disabled for 1 minute and when it is clickable again +25 points are added to a div. The problem is: When the timer is over it says "0:00". Is there a way to replace the "0:00" with "Collect"? I found similar questions on stackoverflow but they didn't help me.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
startCountDown();

function getCounter(){
  return  parseInt($('#counter').html());
}
function setCounter(count) {
  $('#counter').html(count);
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  setCounter(getCounter()+25);
  $('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
  startCountDown();
});

function startCountDown() {
  var minutes = 0,
    seconds = 59;
  $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
  var count = setInterval(function() {
    if (parseInt(minutes) < 0 || parseInt(seconds) <=0 ) {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      clearInterval(count);
      $('#btn').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      seconds--;
      if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="counter">0</div>
<button id="btn">
<span id="countdown">0:00</span>
</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my code as you can see in the second snippet. Unfortunately, I now have the problem that the number 0:01 has been replaced with "Collect". (So: 0:03, 0:02, Collect(disabled), Collect(enabled)). Here is the code:

```js
$('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
    startCountDown();

    function getCounter(){
        return  parseInt($('#counter').html());
    }
    function setCounter(count) {
        $('#counter').html(count);
    }

    $("#btn").click(function() {
        setCounter(getCounter()+25);
        $('#btn').prop('disabled',true);
        startCountDown();
    });

    function startCountDown() {
        var minutes = 0,
            seconds = 60;
        $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        var count = setInterval(function() {
            if (parseInt(minutes) < 0 || parseInt(seconds) <=0 ) {
                $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                clearInterval(count);
                $('#btn').prop('disabled',false);
            } else {
                $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                seconds--;
                if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;}
            if (seconds == 0) {// replacing 0:00 with "Collect" is right here 
                $('#countdown').html("Collect");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="counter">0</div>
<button id="btn">
    <span id="countdown">Collect</span>
</button>
```

Comment: It seems you have a place in your code where you know the timer is complete, right? Just set the HTML to "Collect" instead of `minutes + ":" + seconds` at that place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello GuciiBananaKing99,

I have found the solution to your problem. You need to add an if statement when `seconds` is 0. Then change `$('#btn').html` to `"Collect"`.

Here is the full code:

```
function startCountDown() {
  var minutes = 0,
    seconds = 59;
  $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
  var count = setInterval(function() {
    if (parseInt(minutes) < 0 || parseInt(seconds) <=0 ) {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      clearInterval(count);
      $('#btn').prop('enabled',false);
    } else {
      $("#countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
      seconds--;
      if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}
      if (seconds == 0) { // Check if seconds is 0
          $('#btn').html("Collect"); // Change Btn's HTML to Collect
         
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i need! The only problem is, if you code it like this, after 0:02 it says "Collect (disabled)" and a second later it says "Collect(enabled)". And when you click the button, it still says "Collect" (so the timer is not displayed). Thanks for your effort anyway :)